# Linux: root filesystem via network (with authentication)

Tags: linux, networking, authentication, iscsi

I try to create a linux computer which loads its root filesystem from the network. This currently works with NFS, but unfortunately it is not very secure.

The network is just a home network, which means there are many times some other people in the network (visitors, friends, ...). My NFS share doesn't use authentication, and it seems not to be possible to use authentication to mount the root filesystem:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt

Which brings me to my question:
Is there a filesystem or something that can be used as root filesystem for linux and which works over the network and with authentication?

I already found iSCSI, but my BIOS / EFI doesn't support booting from iSCSI.

Comment: Have a look at PXE and iPXE, both support booting from a HTTPS server. Valid certificate will serve as an authentification credential.

Answer (score 1):

Your BIOS should support PXE. You must configure DHCP on a server such that when your system boots up, it provides a pointer to a kernel image and an initrd (initial ram disk) image, usually via TFTP. Your initrd image is itself a tiny version of the OS, capable of loading drivers and running commands if needed. In theory, the entire OS could be run off this image, but usually, it's used to stage the next phase of loading the OS, which at this point can be iSCSI.

Instead of doing iSCSI, your initrd could, for instance, create an secure tunnel to the NFS server. IPSEC will encrypt an entire IP stream, while a socket-based solution will require that NFS use TCP (not UDP).